# ZeroMQ push/pull: how to manage the queue when no pull clients?

Tags: node.js, zeromq

When my pull client are switched off, is there a way to manage the queue build-up on the push server?

I would like to a achieve a capped FIFO message queue during this situation.

(I am using Node.js)

Thx!

Answer (score 0):

That's basically how ZMQ sockets work, by way of the [High Water Mark](http://api.zeromq.org/2-1%3azmq-setsockopt).  By default it's set to 1000, if I recall correctly.  You can manage it by using setsocketopt (details in the link, and it's fairly straight forward in the node ZMQ binding docs and tests).

It'll queue up messages up to the High Water Mark, then it'll start discarding any new messages that you try to add to the stack.